# InvalidOperationException on Winforms Calling Base.Dispose() when closing window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, invalidoperationexception

Hello im pretty new to c# just downloaded VS2012 and created my new Application, but im getting a really strange Exception, I guess its my fault but again im really new to this

the exception occours when closing form2 that form1 created. this only occurs when an object its placed on form2.

I just got `2 forms` with a button on each, button on form1 calls form2, when form2 is closed I show again form1, after a few seconds it throws `InvalidOperationException` on line base.Dispose

here is the code that trhows the exception

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing); // here is the exceptjion
        }
```

Here is form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var frm = new Form2(this);
            frm.Show(this);
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
```

Here is form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form frm;

    public Form2(Form frm) : this()
    {
        this.frm = frm;
    }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        frm.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Here is the stacktrace

```
No se controló System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Operación no válida a través de subprocesos: Se tuvo acceso al control 'button1' desde un subproceso distinto a aquel en que lo creó.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_InternalHandle()
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.DestroyHandle()
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       en System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       en System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Form.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       en PruebaExceocion.Form2.Dispose(Boolean disposing) en c:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PruebaExceocion\PruebaExceocion\Form2.Designer.cs:línea 20
       en System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
       en System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmClose(Message& m)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       en System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Because form2 is the child of form1, you should not dispose it but hide it instead. Later in time you may want to call it up again.

Comment: @BunnyPigtails But what if I dont want it anymore? also im not explicitly calling Dispose, Net its doing for me isnt it??

Comment: You need to override the Close method and set one of its parameters to an appropriate flag to clear off the above exception. Overriding is done on the form2's source code

Comment: Answer this question if that works will give you the points :)

Comment: ahhh the Stoopid of me now I know Why. Im calling close when the windows is already closing!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you just simply program with 2 forms, then calling one from the other's button can be done also simply like

```
    //On form1
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
    }
```

And no more, you can close the second form whenever you want without any error (I tested this on vs12). It will create a new instance of the Form2 with each button click.
So it becomes a bit trickier if you only want one and the same instance of form2 displayed with each click.

Comment: This is a memory leak. Form is disposable.

Answer (score 0):

Cancel it and hide it.. like so:

```
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Hide();
    frm.Show();
}
```